# Not able to see saved files inside azure storage container

Tags: crystal-reports, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

```
string filePath = @"C:\test.pdf";
CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("DxRecordForm");
FileStream localDirDxRecordForm = File.Create(filePath);
localDirDxRecordForm.Close();
dxCodeReport.ExportToDisk(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, filePath);

using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
{
      blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
}
```

I am exporting a crystal report into pdf format and then saving the pdf in azure storage container. In above code dxCodereport is an instance of crystal report. When I view my storage container, I see the block blob named DxRecordForm. When I click that, I am also able to see the pdf version of my crystal report.
I am not sure why I don't see the file Test.pdf inside my container. I just see the block blob with content-type application/octet-stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code snippet above uploads the file C:\test.pdf to a block blob named DxRecordForm. This would not result in creating a blob named test.pdf. If you would like to upload it a blob named test.pdf, please use "test.pdf" when getting a block blob reference.